# Aggregating coverage report of multiple testng suites

Tags: java, testng, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have developed a Maven project where I have multiple testng.xml files that my code.  I am currently using jacoco and it gives me a separate coverage report for each test.

Is there a way of combining the coverage report of all of these tests into one single HTML File?